# Drupal 7 Display data from database

Tags: drupal

Hi I am new to drupal and I need some direction to start this simple task. My aim is to fetch data from database and display these data on a separate page with specific url but theme is still the same. I tried to using view but it only allows to attach specific content. So where should i start with and there is any specific tutorial that i can have a look.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty advanced stuff (If you don't want to get the data from the content types). If you do you should install the Panels module, which will allow you to override specific pages depending on the url and allow you through the views module to show the Content Type data any way you want.

If that is not the case then you should implement your own php code. That can happen using the drupal hooks. An example for your case is [menu hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). There is a tutorial for creating modules [for dupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/361112). There are others for drupal 6 etc, but the philosophy is the same.

Comment: thank you. Yes it is not really thing to do as a whole task. Thanks for your response

Comment: Feel free to ask for more information if you think of something more you want.